# How can I manage the download of m3u8 file by ffmpeg?

Tags: http, ffmpeg, download, m3u8

How can I **manage** the **download** of **m3u8** file by **ffmpeg**?

```
ffmpeg -i "url" -c copy -y "video.mp4"
```

**How can I manage the download request?**

For example, stop downloading

Download reload

Download from the stopped value onwards

And many other things that can be done for **management**

Comment: Try youtube-dl instead. ffmpeg isn't optimized to be a download tool.

Comment: There are many GUI tools for ffmpeg, that maybe you can get idea from it, see: https://github.com/amiaopensource/ffmpeg-amia-wiki/wiki/3)-Graphical-User-Interface-Applications-using-FFmpeg for example HandBrake is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic `ffmpeg` Not built for download operations. For this reason, it may not be powerful.
Its main power is for convert video.

However, you can use some keys in the terminal environment:

- the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key to stop operations.
- the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key to pause.
- the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to continue.

Comment: So the correct answer is that it is not possible to manage the download by ffmpeg

Comment: @erfan It depends on what your exact definition of management is. If it refers to things like stopping, pausing, continuing, and so on, it can be done as mentioned. Unless you mean managing something other than that, in which case I'm unaware and you must made it transparent!